# A Book with a Tree and Boy on the Cover

Tags: identification-request

I’m looking for a book I read about 7-4 years ago, and I remember some parts of it very clearly but can’t remember the name or author or anything.

- I’m pretty sure it was originally written in English
- I found it from my local public library (in Virginia, USA)
- It’s a kid’s book, middle grade
- Each chapter title starts with “In which”
- I think the genre might’ve been mystery? It reminded me a lot of “A Series of Unfortunate Events” by Lemony Snicket
- The cover is an illustration of a tree, with a boy almost hidden in the top corner, sitting in the branches. I found it kind of eerie: there were darker colors, it seemed painted and detailed, and the style was more realistic than cartoony
- I don’t really remember the plot, and I could be getting this mixed up with another book, but I believe at the end one of the main characters turns out to be a prince from a different land?

I know this isn’t a lot to go off of, I’ve searched hundreds of book covers with trees on Goodreads and couldn’t find it so I gave up and came to see if other people could help.

Comment: FWIW, the "In which" trope is covered [here](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InWhichATropeIsDescribed), although I didn't find an entry that seemed to match.

Comment: Hey, thank you, I looked through it too and couldn’t find it